# Может ли быть Ajax-запрос синхронным?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http

Интересует сама терминология. Ajax - это вроде как асинхронный javascript? Но в интернете полно противоречивой информации, где-то пишут, что ajax может быть как синхронным, так и асинхронным, а где-то что только асинхронным. И поэтому вопрос, например, если на сайте динамически обновляемый блок новостей без перезагрузки страницы

> 1) синхронно, когда блокируется вся страница пока не придет ответ это
>   ajax или нет?
>   2) асинхронно, когда ничего не блокируется - это ajax
>   или нет?

Comment: и то и то `ajax`, как ни странно он может быть как синхронным так и нет, читать [ТУТ](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ajax может и правда быть как асинхронным, открывается сразу несколько потоков, так и синхронными, один поток. Дело в том что Ajax, это просто обращение, «асинхронный JS”, по факту, и верно его называть, XMLHttpRequest, в этом названии нет обращения, технологии.